# Post data to database using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I asked yesterday a similar question and i resolved the answer myself in which i wanted to add data into the database using ajax to avoid refreshing the page.

Now, i wish to do the same thing, but update the data in the database.

Im not sure if the issue is caused by having 2 ajax script requests on the same page..

I am trying to submit this form:

**I should probably tell you, this form is in a modal screen**

```
<form id="editarticleform" method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="blog-id" name="blog-id" value="<?php echo $list['id']; ?>">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="blog-title">Article title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="blog-title" name="blog-title" placeholder="Blog title" value="<?php echo $list['blog_title']; ?>" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="blog-content">Article content</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="blog-content" name="blog-content" placeholder="Blog content" required><?php echo $list['blog_body']; ?></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputFile">Article image</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="article-image" name="article-image" aria-describedby="fileHelp" value="<?php echo $list['blog_image']; ?>">
                <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">This is the image that will appear along side the article.</small>
              </div>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend>Active</legend>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="active-inactive" id="optionsRadios1" value="1" checked>
                    Article is active - Will be shown in the blog.
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="active-inactive" id="optionsRadios2" value="0">
                    Article is inactive - Will not show.
                  </label>
                </div>
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend>Comments</legend>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="enable-comments" id="enable-comments1" value="1" checked>
                    Enable comments - Users can post comments
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="enable-comments" id="enable-comments2" value="0" aria-describedby="disableComments">
                    Disable comments - Users cannot post comments
                    <small id="disableComments" class="form-text text-muted">If you disable comments for users, administrators will still be able to post comments.</small>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <button type="submit" id="edit_article" name="edit_article" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </form>
```

Updating the database using this script:

```
<?php

require_once("../../includes/database.class.php");
session_start();
$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];

$id = $_POST['blog-id'];
$title = $_POST['blog-title'];
$content = $_POST['blog-content'];
$image = $_POST['article-image'];
$active = $_POST['active-inactive'];
$comments = $_POST['enable-comments'];

$sql = "UPDATE blog_article SET blog_title = '$title', blog_body = '$content', blog_image = '$image', active = '$active', comments = '$comments' WHERE id = '$id'";

// print_r($sql);
$result = $database->query($sql);

if ($result) {
    echo "Article updated.";
}else {
    echo "Query failed" . print_r($sql);
}

?>
```

Via AJAX to avoid refreshing the page:

```
<script>

var submit = $('#edit_article');

submit.click(function() {
  var data = $("#editarticleform").serialize();

var update_div = $('#update_div');

$.ajax({
    data: data,
    type: 'post',
    url: '/editarticle.php',  
    success:function(html){
       update_div.html(html);
    }
});
});
  </script>
```

As with the last question, the script works perfectly fine if i directly set the form action to the editarticle.php script. When i implement the ajax script, it doesn't update the database.

I am unsure if its got something to do with the blog-id, but thats what my head immediately thinks it is.. Or it may be that i am being blind and its a tiny little issue..

Comment: Check developers console.

Comment: I have, and it doesnt show anything..

Comment: Do you see ajax-request to your page in console?

Comment: The easiest thing you could do is compare the network traffic from your page to your server in both cases. Your browser developer tools will give you that info. If it's exactly the same, then you know your problem is in your client.

Comment: Try to get output of array: `submit.click(function() {
  var data = $("#editarticleform").serialize();
  alert(data);
});`      
What's output show

Comment: @u_mulder no, its blank

Comment: @CKG there is no output.. Which would leave me to believe its jquery.. but my other form works perfectly fine.. Im not sure if it makes a difference or not, but this form is in a bootstrap modal box..

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following to debug;

- Check what you are sending to the php file, to see if blog-id value is not empty. by doing `var data = $("#editarticleform").serialize();
  console.log(data);`
- Change your ajax url to  `url: 'editarticle.php'` ,because it seems your ajax probably doesn't see the php file.

Comment: I forgot to mention, this form is in a modal screen via bootstrap modal. Im not sure if that makes a difference, but the console is not displaying anything

Comment: Ok. log anything to the console on click to see if your click event is running .if its not you can do 

$('body').on('click','#edit_article',function(){
})
or $("#editarticleform").submit(function(){
})

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the click event isn't triggered. Perhaps try something like this:

```
<script>
// Wait for document ready
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#edit_article', function() {
        var data = $("#editarticleform").serialize();
        var update_div = $('#update_div');

        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'post',
            url: '/editarticle.php',  
            success: function(html){
                update_div.html(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Check the Network tab of your browser's developer tools to see that anything gets sent to the backend, and the request headers to see if all the necessary data is included.

Comment: Have you included jquery file in the head of the file?also check alert(data) before calling ajax what is the output?

Comment: Can you at least see if a request is made in the Network tab, and if the requests includes any data at all (see request headers)? Alternatively, have a look at the [shown.bs.modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) event.

Answer (score 0):

if you use modal bootstrap try this :

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   var submit = $('#edit_article');

   submit.click(function () {
     var data = $("#editarticleform").serialize();

     var update_div = $('#update_div');

     $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: 'post',
        url: '/editarticle.php',
        success: function (html) {
            update_div.html(html);
        }
     });
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
<script>
// Wait for document ready
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#edit_article").click(function() {
        var data = $("#editarticleform").serialize();
        var update_div = $('#update_div');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'editarticle.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: data,     
            success: function(html){
                update_div.html(html);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            }  
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

If still doesn't work try to send raw data with ajax and check if it works

```
data: "blog-id="+blog-id
```